# Optimal control of a boiler: using Fluid Library w. the DynamicPipe component using JModelica

Tags: modelica, jmodelica

Im interested in using **JModelica** together with a model I have constructed in **Dymola**.

Specifically, I have a model of a boiler using the **DynamicPipe** component, and I then just transfer heat to the pipe to warm up the water inside it, and employ a pump component to control the pressure difference over the entire boiler. The model compiles just fine to an **FMU** using **JModelica** and I am able to simulate it without any problems.

However, I now wan't to find an optimal control sequence to bring the boiler into a certain operating point and here things stop working.

I have written a .mop file with an optimization problem, but when I call **transfer_optimization_problem**, I get the following error:

```
Warning: Ignored enumeration typed variable:
eval parameter Modelica.Fluid.Types.ModelStructure boiler.boilerFMU.boiler.pipe.modelStructure = Modelica.Fluid.Types.ModelStructure.av_b "Determines whether flow or volume models are present at the ports" /* Modelica.Fluid.Types.ModelStructure.av_b */
Java error occurred:
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException: Cannot convert expression to MX: size(A, 1)
at org.jmodelica.optimica.compiler.FExp.toMX(FExp.java:4516)
at org.jmodelica.optimica.compiler.FMaxExp.toMX(FMaxExp.java:560)
at org.jmodelica.optimica.compiler.FExp.toMXVector(FExp.java:4497)
at org.jmodelica.optimica.compiler.FAssignStmt.updateExpressionsAccordingToStatement(FAssignStmt.java:385)
at org.jmodelica.optimica.compiler.FFunctionDecl.generateFinalExpressionVector(FFunctionDecl.java:1365)
at org.jmodelica.optimica.compiler.FFunctionDecl.toMXFunction_compute(FFunctionDecl.java:2878)
at org.jmodelica.optimica.compiler.FFunctionDecl.toMXFunction(FFunctionDecl.java:2865)
at org.jmodelica.optimica.compiler.FFunctionCall.toMXVector(FFunctionCall.java:1578)
at org.jmodelica.optimica.compiler.FFunctionCallStmt.updateExpressionsAccordingToStatement(FFunctionCallStmt.java:391)
at org.jmodelica.optimica.compiler.FFunctionDecl.generateFinalExpressionVector(FFunctionDecl.java:1365)
at org.jmodelica.optimica.compiler.FFunctionDecl.toMXFunction_compute(FFunctionDecl.java:2878)
at org.jmodelica.optimica.compiler.FFunctionDecl.toMXFunction(FFunctionDecl.java:2865)
at org.jmodelica.optimica.compiler.FFunctionCall.toMXVector(FFunctionCall.java:1578)
at org.jmodelica.optimica.compiler.FFunctionCallStmt.updateExpressionsAccordingToStatement(FFunctionCallStmt.java:391)
at org.jmodelica.optimica.compiler.FFunctionDecl.generateFinalExpressionVector(FFunctionDecl.java:1365)
at org.jmodelica.optimica.compiler.FFunctionDecl.toMXFunction_compute(FFunctionDecl.java:2878)
at org.jmodelica.optimica.compiler.FFunctionDecl.toMXFunction(FFunctionDecl.java:2865)
at org.jmodelica.optimica.compiler.FFunctionCall.toMXVector(FFunctionCall.java:1578)
at org.jmodelica.optimica.compiler.FFunctionCall.toMX(FFunctionCall.java:1562)
at org.jmodelica.optimica.compiler.FDotSubExp.toMX(FDotSubExp.java:544)
at org.jmodelica.optimica.compiler.FVariable.parameterEquationToMXBindingExpression(FVariable.java:3807)
at org.jmodelica.optimica.compiler.FVariable.findMXBindingExpressionIfPresent(FVariable.java:3770)
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "boiler_opt.py", line 89, in <module>
op = transfer_optimization_problem("BoilerOptimization.Opt", paths, compiler_log_level='error')
File "/opt/jmodelica/Python/pyjmi/casadi_interface.py", line 171, in transfer_optimization_problem
accept_model=accept_model)
File "/opt/jmodelica/Python/modelicacasadi_transfer/modelica_casadi_transfer_wrapper.py", line 156, in transfer_optimization_problem
_get_options(compiler_options), compiler_log_level)
File "/opt/jmodelica/Python/modelicacasadi_transfer/modelica_casadi_transfer_wrapper.py", line 179, in _transfer_optimica
return modelicacasadi_wrapper._transferOptimizationProblem(ocp, class_name, files, options, log_level)
File "/opt/jmodelica/Python/modelicacasadi_wrapper/modelicacasadi_wrapper.py", line 3417, in _transferOptimizationProblem
return _modelicacasadi_wrapper._transferOptimizationProblem(*args)
RuntimeError: a java error occurred; details were printed
```

Apparently, it is not so happy about an enumerate type in the **DynamicPipe** model which specifies the model structure.

To check that it is indeed my model that was the problem, I linearized it and used the linearised version in the optimization problem; *this ran perfectly.*

Any idea on how to handle this? :-)

Regards,

Joakim

**UPDATE:**
I asked the same question on the JModelica forums, with the following response. However, I have not yet found a solution to circumvent the errors: http://www.jmodelica.org/27776#comment-6467

Comment: Not too familiar with the components or `Optimica`, but can you try to make the problem a little bit easier to linearize by relaxing the system somewhat?

Comment: Hmm - I think the problem is the use of some special language construct in Modelica, which Optimica/JModelica is not to fond of -- and thus not so much related to how well posed the system is. I posed the same question on the [JModelica forums](http://www.jmodelica.org/27776). But I will look into it :-)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So an acceptable answer was provided on the JModelica forums by Fredrik:
http://www.jmodelica.org/27776#comment-6468

Simply put: **The MSL Media Library is not supported.**

My solution was to instead built my own small fluid library specifically for my use case - this was a no-brainer in the case of single-phase water, and it works perfectly. But I must admit, that it would have been nice to be able to use the MSL Fluid Library, to not lock myself in with my own fluid interface.